# Eliminate a specific pattern from text

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this text coming from an API:

```html
<p style="font-color:#000;font-weight:bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>
<p style="font-color:#000;font-weight:500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>
```

I am trying to eliminate the `style="font-weight: bold ..etc"` from the text wherever it occurs, then split the paragraphs and put them in an array. I used regexp and I have tried a lot but none of my tries seems to solve the problem.

The language is javascript:

```js
t1=text.replace(/^style*\"$/g, '')
t2=t1.split(/(<\/?p*>$)/gm)
```

Comment: I'd personally just append these to the document and then queryselect them all and loop over them to get the innerText.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is browser-side JavaScript, then, as @JamesCoyle suggests, it would much better to use the DOM to do this.

*(Insert easily googled rant about how you shouldn't be using regular expression to parse HTML here)*

```
const html = '<p style="font-color:#000;font-weight:bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>\n<p style="font-color:#000;font-weight:500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>'

extractParagraphTexts(html);

function extractParagraphTexts(html) {
   const tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
   tempDiv.innerHTML = html;

   const result = [];
   tempDiv.querySelectorAll("p").forEach(e => result.push(e.textContent));

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this work just fine for me, also thank you for the advice about parsing HTML with regexp

Answer (score 1):

You can try this....

```
const text = "<p style='font-color:#000;font-weight:bold'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p><p style='font-color:#000;font-weight:500'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>";
```

```
str = text.replace(/style='[^']*'/g, '');
```

**OR**

```
str = text.replace(/style="[^"]*"/g, '');
```

now for split p tags...

```
str = str.substring(1, str.length-1);
let strArray = str.split(/></g);
for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
    strArray[i] = '<' + strArray[i] + '>';
}
console.log(strArray);
```

**Output**

```
[
"<p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>",
"<p >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>"
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much , for me the second option of `replace` has worked ..

Answer (score -1):

You too close to answer just improve regx:

```js
var t1 = '<p style="font-color:#000;font-weight:bold">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p><p style="font-color:#000;font-weight:500">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore</p>';
   
    t1 = t1.replace(/style=\"[\S]+\"/gm, '');
    console.log(t1);
```